# Custom Detail Image View from Three20

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

I am pretty new with Three20. I have followed ray wenderlich's nice [introduction to three20](http://www.raywenderlich.com/656/introduction-to-three20) and the examples within the three20 framework. When I click on a thumbnail in a thumbnail view (subclass of `TTThumbsViewController`) to launch a Details view, a standard Details image view (deployed by `TTPhotoViewController` or its super class). I would like to use my own implementation of a Details View instead of the default. I put the following code when I initiated the subclass of `TTThumbsViewController` and `TTThumbsViewControllerDelegate` method:

```
- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<TTThumbsViewControllerDelegate>)delegate {
    [super initWithDelegate:delegate];
    return self;
}

- (void)thumbsViewController: (TTThumbsViewController*)controller 
              didSelectPhoto: (id<TTPhoto>)photo {
    [navigationController.pushViewController:photoDetailViewController 
                                    animated:Yes];
}
```

But the default `TTPhotoViewController` view still prevail. When I put a NSLog in the delegate method. I coud see the method was called. I think there is another delegate someone already set in `TTThumViewController`? Can someone recommend a way to display my detail photo view? Is there another thumbs view controller I can use? Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was able to do a cheat to load my own Detail Image View by the following: (1) add self.delegate = self in TTThumbsViewController subclass, then (2) add thumbsViewController:didSelectPhoto: { //do push a new navigation controller here }, (3) add - (TTPhotoViewController*)createPhotoViewController { return nil;}  Now it does what I want, but in debugger it complains: Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController: 0x28e2d0>. because in step (3) I forced it to return a nil view controller. If anyone has a better solution, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm really new to all of this (coding, etc.) but I'll share what I've found. By looking up the definition of ttthumbsviewcontroller, I was able to find the following method(wrong term?):-

```
- (void)thumbsTableViewCell:(TTThumbsTableViewCell*)cell didSelectPhoto:(id<TTPhoto>)photo {
  [_delegate thumbsViewController:self didSelectPhoto:photo];

  BOOL shouldNavigate = YES;
  if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(thumbsViewController:shouldNavigateToPhoto:)]) {
    shouldNavigate = [_delegate thumbsViewController:self shouldNavigateToPhoto:photo];
  }

  if (shouldNavigate) {
    NSString* URL = [self URLForPhoto:photo];
    if (URL) {
      TTOpenURLFromView(URL, self.view);

    } else {
      TTPhotoViewController* controller = [self createPhotoViewController];
      controller.centerPhoto = photo;
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
  }
}
```

In the else statement, I've found this calls the creation of the photoviewcontroller. By recalling this method (?) in the actual body of my own code and changing the body in the else statement I was able to add a custom detail view. Further down the definition of the ttthumbsnailviewcontroller, you can find that the creatPhotoViewController calls for an initiation of the PhotoViewController so calling that method(?) in the body of the code and initializing another view also works.

If someone can explain whether or not this is a good method of doing this (I have a feeling that is not), it would be appreciated. Also why does putting the method in the body of the code override the call there.